# Can we show a custom pop to the tridion user on component save through Event System

Tags: event-system

I have a requirement in Tridion 2013 where i need to show a pop up to the Tridion user on Component save . I want to show a custom message to the user through popup.

What best we could do with Event System here .

Comment: Instead of popup, you can use `notifications` in `info bar`

Comment: The added benefit is the notification would be visible and available across windows.

Comment: The event system cant access the message center as fair as I know...

Comment: Saurabh : Basically you are saying that i need to write GUI extension to do so and i need to trigger javascript event on component save which will show the message in notification bar.

Answer (score 2):

The only interaction you can do with a user from the event system is to show an error message.

If you need interaction with the user then you'd have to build a UI extension, do check these 2 blog posts for more info and examples.

http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html

http://www.curlette.com/?p=913

Or, if you're feeling inspired, you can try using SignalR: http://www.curlette.com/?p=1156

Answer (score 1):

It's common to hear that 'X is a requirement' when the X that is described is actually an implementation detail. The Tridion GUI is already pretty well thought through, and works for thousands of users without a component save popup. From a usability standpoint - you might question why you want to create extra work for the content team like this. It will be irritating and frustrating to have to dismiss an extra popup every time they create a component.

One solution to your problem may be to challenge the requirement. This doesn't mean you have to be difficult about it, but it's fair enough to go back to whoever gave you this assignment and say something like: "I'm being asked to implement a popup, but the business case for this isn't clear to me. I'll need to know what we're actually trying to achieve before I can come up with the appropriate design."

Maybe the requirement has come from someone who won't actually be working with the system, and who hasn't consulted the real end users. In any case, the conversation is worth having. You may end up implementing something different that has far more business value.

Comment: Dominic: They actually want to show a popup or a notification to content author that don't forget to add the changed components to Bundle for workflow. They want to do this to avoid unapproved content should not go to Live. As soon as someone created/modified the component , just show a popup/notification to add it to bundle and start workflow.

Comment: Might it not make more sense then to have the event add the item to the bundle?

Comment: i have 5 components on a page and inside these 5 components again i have linked and nested component. i want to be sure that relevant workflow triggers on relevant content. Out of these 5 , 4 component Schema are generic and used across different content pages. So as a precaution we just want to show a notification to user after saving his changes that please add these items to bundle and start workflow soon. So my question was what is the best possible way to just show the notification.

Comment: As Nuno has said, you can build a GUI Extension, however, I'd suggest you take the design thinking further than a simple popup. As I said, needing an extra click to get the job done is annoying, and as a reminder, it will very quickly stop working once people learn to dismiss it automatically. Remember when Tridion used to nag you with a popup when you made a schema change? Did that *ever* save you from doing something stupid?

Comment: And BTW, if you configure your schema to _require_ a bundle workflow, then Tridion itself will prompt your users to add it to a bundle when editors click save & close